# WebDriverException Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH ( Error on mac M1)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying web scrapping with selenium and therefore following the below code.
However, I encounter an error with chromedriver path, I am unable to figure out on mac M1 . I've tried several methods to solve this.

Any hints?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = Options()

chromeOptions.headless = False

s = Service("usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= s, options = chromeOptions )
```

I am getting the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SeleniumManagerException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     95                 try:
---> 96                     path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(browser)
     97                 except WebDriverException as new_err:

7 frames
SeleniumManagerException: Message: Selenium manager failed for: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome. /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in _start_process(self, path)
    210         except OSError as err:
    211             if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
--> 212                 raise WebDriverException(
    213                     f"'{os.path.basename(self.path)}' executable needs to be in PATH. {self.start_error_message}"
    214                 )

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide also the file name of the webdriver in the path, so in your case:

```
usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

should be like:

```
usr/local/bin/chromedriver/chromedriver
```

if the name of the folder matches the webdriver file name.
At least according to the error it seems like chromedriver is a folder where you have placed the real webdriver file.

Comment: when I tried  **which chromedriver** on the terminal, I found  `/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver` as the path. Still, it throws the same error. The file is not in any folder right now.

Comment: You need to download the webdriver for MAC from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and put it inside the folder or somewhere else and provide path include driver file name

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip

Comment: I have downloaded the chromedriver, could you please help me with how to put it inside the right folder? because the current path I am giving doesn't work too, that is in my downloads folder right now.

Comment: Open terminal in the folder where the unzipped chromedriver is and execute this command: cp chromedriver usr/local/bin/chromedriver

Comment: Not sure why I see no result after executing the command in the same terminal. When I click on the UNIX executable file, I get the message, chromedriver was started successfully.

Comment: This is expected.

Comment: Is there any stance on not having the `GLIBC_2.28` not found error associated with this issue, as mentioned above? Also, is it required to have Linux installed on the system to install that?

Comment: Just noticed chromedriver v108 is not yet released for M1, that is probably the reason. Thank you for the help. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Make sure you download the right driver arm64